# Render view is different from Camera Viewport and the passepartout is missing

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm fairly new to Blender, and I might be making an obvious mistake.

I'm having problems with the camera viewport and rendering. My camera view (Numb Pad 0) and the rendering (F12) are different. The rendering is much bigger. I also miss the passepartout, although the check mark is set. The most blender stuff is in english maybe I just don't search with the right words :). In every tutorial they say the camera viewport ( Numb pad 0) is the same as the render. So I am a little bit confused and sure I have activated or deactivated something.

In another question there was a similar Problem but i couldn't comment. But there was the idea of checking clip start and End from the viewport and the camera viewport. There was a mistake but sadly it did not changed the different size of the rendering.

It would be great if you could give me some advice :)[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to scroll out (backwards) in *camera view*, to see the actual frame.

Comment: Hi @brockmann , first: Thank you :). I tried this but it moved the camera. Maybe I did something wrong. When  I am in Camera view (Numbpad 0) i am pressing "G" and I am scrolling back with middle mouse. (I tried it with command + g too.) 
That was a suggestion, right?

In the "normal view" its clear I moved the camera instead.

Comment: Hi @LisaPohl. My suggestion was to scroll backwards using the mouse wheel to reveal the camera bounds...

Comment: Hi @brockmann, i tried it and it is working exactly like you said with another file i did. Just this stupid little Donut-File doesn't want to work. Is there another mode here that I could have accidentally activated?

Comment: Consider sharing the file preferably using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=aKpKY8Xb" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/aKpKY8Xb/)

Comment: hi @susu thank you :). "Lock to Camera View" works exactly as shown in all my other files. (Sorry, took a little time to review.) But that frame or passepatout is still missing (in this file )and I don't think I zoomed in too much. I am sure i am making some beginner mistake maybe its so obvios..

Comment: @brockmann okay, shared the link in the comment above. Sorry I'm not sure if I have to mention you or not for you to see :). So if you can find time it would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: @LisaPohl please ask only one question per post. For different questions open a new question.

Comment: I know, I already added the file to the question so everyone can take a look @LisaPohl